# SQL INSERT INTO two tables from one table

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the app Tinder and the following numbers:

```
(User_id, target_id)
(1,2);
(2,1);
(3,5)
(5,3);
(4,1);
```

This means that 1 and 2 have matched, and 3 and 5, but not 4 and 1. 
Now for my question. I have two tables in MySQL database currently. `User` and `Likes`. 
Where `User` has bunch of values, but `id` is the important one (image 1). 
`Likes` has two values: `user_id` and `target_id` (image 2).

**How should I approach getting the data from `User` into the columns of `Likes`?** This should result in the `target_id` and `user_id` of `Likes` having the same values as `id`of `User`. Am I even going at this correctly?

I know that one has a bunch of columns, and the other has two, and that is where I can't figure out any more.

[image: SQL ID]

[image: User_id, target_id]

Comment: "This means that 1 and 2 have matched, and 3 and 5, but not 4 and 1." but `(4, 1)` is also in your set, why don't they match? And I don't understand "This should result in the `target_id` and `user_id` of `Likes` having the same values as `id` of `User`." aren't that already user IDs in there? If not, what are they and how do they relate to a user?

Comment: @stickybit, (4, 1) is not a match because it only goes in one direction. You need a two pairs that are the opposite, `(x, y) AND (y, x)`

Comment: Ah OK, thanks for the clarification. I got at least that part...

Comment: @user6076, your question is very incomplete. You want to insert two user id for each row in the `Likes` table but what is the issue your having?

Comment: Do you want to construct table user out of Likes
or you want to change the table Likes in such a way that if (a, b) is in Likes then (b, a) be in Likes too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is kind of vague. Actually I don't know if you want to filter out the non-paired users or you just wanna to include the users info to the "Like". I think you want to find which user pairs like each other.
to  do so you can use a query like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE LikeEachOther(
SELECT DISTINCT‌ L1.user_id, L1.target_id 
FROM Likes L1, Likes L2 
WHERE‌ L1.user_id = L2.target_id and L2.user_id = L2.target_id
);‌‌‌
SELECT *
FROM LikeEachOther LEO, User U1, User U2
WHERE U1.User_id = LEO.USer_id and U2.User_id = LEO.target_id
```

Comment: No, the question is about inserting data into the `Likes` table,

Comment: would you please explain what you want to insert into likes and from where?

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for. Checking pairs, but also I tried to see if I could insert data from `Likes` into `User`. Thanks